# tflite_convert command not found ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained my tensorflow 1.15 ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized model and want to export it in .tflite format. I have already ran the export_tflite_ssd_graph.py and have generated the saved_model.pb file. The  next step would be to run a convert_tflite script like this:

```
tflite_convert \
--input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb \
--output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_values=128 \
--change_concat_input_ranges=false \
--allow_custom_ops
```

From this tutorial: https://gilberttanner.com/blog/convert-your-tensorflow-object-detection-model-to-tensorflow-lite/. But I get a **tflite_convert command not found error**. How should I get the tflite_convert file???

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve your goals one way is to use model.save where you can continue the running codes and model. I think the command is someone builds scripts, you can build from these templates.

Sample: Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Save
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.save(
    saved_model_dir,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None,
    save_traces=True
)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model( saved_model_dir )
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open( saved_model_dir + '\\model.tflite', 'wb' ) as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

Sample 2: Converting a build model to a TensorFlow Lite model.

```
tf_lite_model_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(
    model
) 
tflite_model = tf_lite_model_converter.convert()

with open(checkpoint_dir + '\\model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```